# Why can't I post my form information from my local environment?

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, post, xss

I am trying to understand why the following code works on my server but not on my localhost through browser-sync (I am using gulp):

```
$.ajax({
          url: 'https://www.someserver.com/Form.aspx',
          type: 'POST',
          dataType: 'html',
          data: {
            'email': email
            'key': key
          },
          success: function(data) {
            console.log(data);
          },
          error: function(error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
        });
```

On my server, I get a success response.  On my local environment (running on localhost:3000), I immediately get the following error:

```
Cannot POST /
```

At first, I thought it might be the fact that I the target url is https and I was serving my local environment through regular http.  But, when I switch my browser-sync process to run over https, I get the same error.

Does anyone know why I cannot post my form information from my local environment?

Answer (score 1):

The URL for the ajax call will be different between the two computers.  You need to either use relative urls, or code some mechanism that helps the javascript to calculate the correct URL (based from the CURRENT root directory, which can change between the two computers).

I usually inject the current root directory high up in the page, i.e.

```
window.siteInfo = {root: "/somepath/again/"}
```

and then in my javascript, I append to get correct urls, i.e.

```
window.location = window.siteInfo.root + "someOtherpage.html"
```

Comment: thanks for your response.  I see your point about the path-ing issues, however, I am using an absolute URL in the code.  Shouldn't that mitigate the problem you describe in your answer?

Comment: If your HTML is being served from server xyz.com, you can't make an AJAX call to server abc.com without some configuration.  The default result is that the ajax call will fail.  You probably DON'T want an absolute url, which is why my response says you need a constant relative url (which could be "../../page.aspx") or to calculate it.

Comment: This is a pretty common problem, actually.